# how can i fix the problem > i try a lot but i can not do it fix the error no module in wsgi

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\PC\PycharmProjects\django\mysite>heroku logs --tail
2020-06-18T01:04:20.778014+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-18T01:04:24.869607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mysite.wsgi`
2020-06-18T01:04:28.014639+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-18T01:04:28.015240+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48019 (4)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.015347+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-06-18T01:04:28.019958+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027799+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027801+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027819+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027820+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027820+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027820+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027821+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027821+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027822+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027822+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027823+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027823+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027824+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027824+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027825+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027825+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027826+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027826+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027826+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027827+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027828+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027828+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027829+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027835+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-06-18T01:04:28.027942+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.052818+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062094+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062095+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062096+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062097+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062097+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062097+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062098+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062098+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062099+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062099+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062099+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062099+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062100+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062100+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062100+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062100+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062100+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062101+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062102+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062104+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062104+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062104+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062104+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062108+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2020-06-18T01:04:28.062218+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-06-18 01:04:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.099491+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T01:04:28.099500+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
2020-06-18T01:04:28.099956+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.099977+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
2020-06-18T01:04:28.100485+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.100490+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 617, in spawn_workers
2020-06-18T01:04:28.100995+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2020-06-18T01:04:28.100998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101274+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101294+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101742+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101806+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101808+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101808+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101809+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101827+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-06-18T01:04:28.101847+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102012+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102033+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102235+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102258+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102560+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102765+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.102785+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103076+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103131+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103487+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103491+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103876+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.103880+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2020-06-18T01:04:28.104162+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-06-18T01:04:28.104281+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-06-18T01:04:28.104604+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-06-18T01:04:28.104635+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-06-18T01:04:28.180230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-18T01:04:28.217466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: i try a lot but i can not fix it  .can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a path issue.

You might have installed gunicorn in your system-wide Python installation, instead of your environment (e.g. venv).

Try to fix it by uninstalling the system gunicorn, and then activating your environment (e.g. venv), and installing gunicorn to the environment (e.g. venv) using `pip install gunicorn`.

See https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html

If you use virtualenv try to add home to django.ini:

```
home=/path/to/venv/
```

To test it through web browser:

```
uwsgi --ini django.ini --protocol=http
```

Comment: 2020-06-18T06:35:46.409553+00:00 app[web.1]: from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2020-06-18T06:35:46.409558+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Comment: Where did you install it? And are you using virtual environments ?

Comment: i use venv package. when i type heroku logs --tail i got it